# Jquery addClass when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class when the checkbox is checked on the div element it belongs..

This is the link to my current code: [http://jsfiddle.net/WH6bz/2/]

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you were using Mootools.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/WH6bz/3/

Also, the *else* condition should be `removeClass()`.

```
$('div.thumb > input:checkbox').change(function () {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest("div.thumb").addClass('highlight');
    }
    else {
        $(this).closest("div.thumb").removeClass('highlight');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're not loading jQuery in your fiddle... Try this shorter code in any case. By using `toggleClass` with the `switch` param you get rid of the `if..else` statement and all that code WETness.

```
$('div.thumb input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('div.thumb').toggleClass('highlight', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WH6bz/4/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have selected **Mootools** instead of jQuery as the jsFiddle framework :D.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You have to select jQuery from the Framework drop down list at the left sidebar of jsFiddle.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UvVvH/

```
$('div.thumb > input:checkbox').change(function () {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest("div.thumb").addClass('highlight');
    }
    else {
        $(this).closest("div.thumb").addClass('highlight');
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

change the frame work moo tools. select jquery and run the code

```
$('div.thumb > input:checkbox').change(function () {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest("div.thumb").addClass('highlight');
    }
    else {
        $(this).closest("div.thumb").removeClass('highlight');
    };

});
```